# Issue in my HTML/CSS email

Tags: html, email, html-email

I know that when i come to HTML email i have to use the Table Layouts. This is what i have done [here](http://jsbin.com/ihuxok/1) Unfortunately when i make some tests with this [online tool](http://ctrlq.org/html-mail/) to my Hotmail and gmail, the layout is not exactly the same. In the email the difference from my [HTML code](http://jsbin.com/ihuxok/1/edit) is that it does not get the same H2 font style and family in the text *`<h2>"Responda correctamente a las preguntas y gane un viaje a Roma!"</h2>`* and the second image is separated from the one on the top and the one on the bottom. What's the best solution to figure it out the issue? How can i achieve the same layout?

Thanks for your time

Comment: There are a ton of things you need to do differently when making an HTML Email vs a plain html page, here's some insight: http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/best-practices-for-coding-html-emails

Comment: Another really important thing is to not have big lines of text without linebreaks. Try to have a maximum characters count per line of 65 and break all the lines. Some e-mail servers and clients rips/delete some chars at certain line lengths, breaking your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on external (`<link rel="stylesheet">`) or embedded style sheets (those contained within the `<style>` tag above the `<body>` tag). This is the most important thing to avoid. Many email services cut everything above the body tag and disable external style sheets. That said you can include a few embedded CSS statements (such as link color) as long as you're ok with them not rendering in some email clients.

Taste this post: http://groundwire.org/labs/email-publishing/using-css-and-html-in-email-newsletters

Comment: Ok, i have used this tool http://premailer.dialect.ca/ to not rely to any external css sheets and make the email services reading just under my body. I got a better result! But it's still not exactly the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `style="display:block;"` to all your img tags and instead of an h2 use a font tag with a style attribute:

```
<font style="color:#202020; font-family: 'Georgia',serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;">
    <b>Some title</b>
</font>
<br>
```

Comment: I am very close to achieve it, this is my new code http://jsbin.com/opokac/1/edit generated by premailer.dialect.ca, but the look is not still the same apart being very close.Got better, but not still the same. I have added style="display:block;" but it s worse